# H2 in-memory database for postgresql | Error Code : 90051

Tags: spring, postgresql, junit, h2

Using h2 in-memory database for unit testing with Spring. The production database is PostgreSQL. I have following script which works fine on Postgres but failing on h2:

```
CREATE TABLE address (
  address_id          SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  province_code       char(2), 
  created_timestamp   timestamp(35) with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
)
```

```
SQL State  : 90051
Error Code : 90051
Message    : Scale($"35") must not be bigger than precision("23");
```

Do I need to specify something else in the URL or configuration. Here is the url:

```
database.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST
```

Comment: Can you use just `timestamp` as type (no parameters)?

Comment: @PM77-1: The problem is that DDL scripts are already created. it will be too much effort to change all of them.

Comment: `timestamp(35)` is invalid for Postgres as well - you will get a warning "*TIMESTAMP(35) WITH TIME ZONE precision reduced to maximum allowed, 6*" - so you should change the (useless) `timestamp(35)` to `timestamp(6)` or simply `timstamp` for **both** database systems